# Why was this Answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deletion, specific-answer

[Who is "The Son" in Hebrews chapter 1: 8 ? Is He God in the strictest sense of the word, or a created being?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/who-is-the-son-in-hebrews-chapter-1-8-is-he-god-in-the-strictest-sense-of-t)

New contributor ROY OOSTHUIZEN posted answer to this.

The answer seemed appropriate, polite, on topic...

It is not there anymore - no trace, except in the home page and recent activity as noted below.

modified 2 hours ago ROY OOSTHUIZEN 1

And suddenly this Q is protected.

Comment: Because it didn't even in the slightest address the actual question.

Comment: So why not address that with the NEW poster? Seems a bit cloak and dagger to me. And maybe that's your opinion...

Comment: I did address it with the poster. And no, it's a pretty clear non-answer, the question is about Hebrews, which the post never mentioned, instead talking about 1 Corinthians and Colossians.

Comment: but why was it deleted so abruptly and with no trace? There are posts on here for years and they get deleted (or not) after some time - this was 10 mins!

Comment: Because I saw it. The right time to delete a non-answer is ASAP. (And it wasn't 10 minutes, it was about 90, not that it matters.) If it doesn't seem fair, feel free to flag old posts for removal.

Comment: LOL, nice work. It was a non-trinitarian answer, so that might help explain it

Comment: Please stop maligning me and the other Trinitarian mods. If you think we are abusing our power [tell the Stack Exchange staff](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/contact).

Comment: ease up - I'm not maligning ANYONE. Just commenting on the way things potentially are. Thanks for all the good you do!

Comment: The poster made no attempt at all to answer the question and made no reference to the text under discussion. I cannot see how anyone could criticise the immediate deletion of this answer.

Comment: It’s all quite arbitrary now, but it still seems a little alarming and reactionary. Hopefully Roy will find somewhere more welcoming to share his journey of discovery.

Answer (score 4):

**Why is the Question Protected?**

Though not all users are able to see all activity on this question, there are actually fifteen submitted answers which have been proposed, including six deleted and one with a large number of downvotes. Questions with this level of continued activity should be protected, to protect against low-quality contributions. It's appropriate for a moderator to protect any question in this kind of instance.

**Why was this Answer Deleted?**

As has been discussed in the comments, this answer makes no mention of the source passage the Question is focused on, and imputes its answer through theology and other passages only. It's appropriate to delete such answers, and then if they are revised to bring them on-topic, they can be undeleted.

Sometimes people get confused about Questions and Answers being treated differently. When users submit Questions which are off-topic, they are usually Closed, and then re-opened if they are revised in line with the site guidelines. Answers, however, cannot be 'closed', and so the only recourses available are comments, flags and deletions. For those unable to see Deleted Answers, this can appear alarming. However, deletions are usually accompanied by a comment to the user, which in this case was both kind and courteous.

**Is there an anti-Trinitarian bias on this Question?**

Probably not. The [top answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/19193/13311) is a non-Trinitarian answer, and only has two downvotes on it. Given that the deleted answer doesn't fit the site guidelines, it's easy to understand why it would be removed without needing to look for additional reasons.

Comment: thx very much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: you're welcome @user48152 - don't worry, we do all try to avoid personal biases as best we can. The user base of the site will always have various doctrinal leans that may affect how each chooses to vote on Questions and Answers, but that's not a precedent or example we'd hope to see from the more experienced users.

Comment: @user48152 - I do particularly appreciate your interest in the experience of a new user on the site, and it's good that you've flagged this as something that could be perceived as doctrinal bias by a new user starting off with their first answer. These are the kinds of everyday experiences that influence the way the community is built up, and so it's good to take a moment to reflect on them.